# Null Pointer Exception when autowiring beans

Tags: java, spring, servlets, autowired

I'm making a simple project for school but I'm stuck.
I have a bean FavoriteService that I need to address. However when autowiring the bean in my servlet I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception and I can't figure out why.

FavoriteService

```
public class FavoriteService {
    @Autowired
    private Users users;

    public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
        return users.login(username, password);
    }

    public void addUser(String rootUsername, String rootPassword, String username, String password)
    {
        if(rootUsername.equals("root") && rootPassword.equals("rootpasswd")) users.addUser(username, password);
    }

    public List<String> getFavorites(String username, String password)
    {
        List<String> favorites;

        if(checkLogin(username, password))
        {
            favorites = users.getFavorites(username);
        } else {
            favorites = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        return favorites;
    }

    public void addFavorite(String username, String password, String favorite)
    {
        if(checkLogin(username, password))
        {
            users.addFavorite(username, favorite);
        }
    }

    public void removeFavorite(String username, String password, String favorite)
    {
        if(checkLogin(username, password))
        {
            users.removeFavorite(username, favorite);
        }
    }
}
```

Servlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Autowired
    private FavoriteService favoriteService;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");

        System.out.println(favoriteService);

        if(favoriteService.checkLogin(username, password))
        {
            resp.sendRedirect("root.jsp");
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

springservlet-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="be.kdg.prog4.tdd"/>
    <bean name="userDao" class="be.kdg.prog4.tdd.UserDaoWithMap" scope="singleton" />
    <bean name="users" class="be.kdg.prog4.tdd.Users" scope="singleton" />
    <bean name="favoriteService" class="be.kdg.prog4.tdd.FavoriteService" scope="singleton" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <display-name>TDD oefening</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>be.kdg.prog4.tdd.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

If you need any more info feel free to ask.
Thanks.

EDIT:

I solved it by doing this in the servlet init

```
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());
}
```

Comment: Try to better define the problem by reducing it, by doing the minimum set of things to see it appears

Comment: As @tomsoft said, try to reduce the code to the part that it is giving an error to you please.

Comment: Or at least the stacktrace of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling LoginServlet you are not going through Spring. You mapped it directly in your web.xml and your set let container is initializing your class without going through Spring and the autowired does not work. You need the access the server through a mapping of springservlet.

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet is not initialized by Spring and therefore the `@Autowired` fields are not getting initialized by Spring.

Instead of using `@Autowired` you can override the Servlet `init()` method and get the Spring web context and use its `getBean` method to get your bean.

This is how you can get the Spring context in your init method:

```
ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution but now I'm getting a null pointer exception on the webapplicationcontext.

this is what I did:

        @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        favoriteService = (FavoriteService) ctx.getBean("favoriteService");
    }